# MySQL select only the correct row with releationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have several tables and have them connected to relationships.
Here is a picture like:
[image]
Since I have several entries in the table Addresses I get more rows while selecting.

This is the SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Users, Infos, Addresses WHERE Users.User_TOKEN = "PMgzdI3T9ji-8waSGUJCfTp-IQBT061TIRF-YqSHuMRN4Zk-fS09BDov27l-D0lK2"
```

---

User-Table:

[image]

Infos-Table:

[image]

Adresses-Table:

[image]

---

How can I get it without working with join?

Comment: You can do it with three queries in PHP. But why don't you want to use joins?

Comment: I have a php function where the tables are set, then selected with WHERE are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't get, why you don't want to use joins. But mybe this will help you:

Your original query already uses joins. But the way you did it, you will get all infos and all addresses for all users. To fix it you need to define join conditions:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users, Infos, Addresses 
WHERE Users.User_TOKEN = "PMgzdI3T9ji-8waSGUJCfTp-IQBT061TIRF-YqSHuMRN4Zk-fS09BDov27l-D0lK2"
    /* join conditions */
    AND Infos.Info_TOKEN = Users.User_Info_TOKEN
    AND Addresses.Address_TOKEN = Infos.Info_Address_TOKEN
```

The folowing query will do the same, but is more readable (imho):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
JOIN Infos i     ON i.Info_TOKEN = u.User_Info_TOKEN
JOIN Addresses a ON a.Address_TOKEN = i.Info_Address_TOKEN
WHERE u.User_TOKEN = "PMgzdI3T9ji-8waSGUJCfTp-IQBT061TIRF-YqSHuMRN4Zk-fS09BDov27l-D0lK2"
```